# Count directories and subdirectories

Tags: linux, shell

I want to combine directories and sub-directories and sum-up the first column as follows:

**original output:**

```
8       ./.g/apps/panel/mon/lt/prefs
12      ./.g/apps/panel/mon/lt      
40      ./.g/apps/panel/mon                         
44      ./.g/apps/panel                                 
88      ./.g/apps                                       
112     ./.g                                            
4       ./.g                                             
4       ./.pof                                            
20      ./.local/share/applications                         
4       ./.local/share/m/packages                        
8       ./.local/share/m                                 
4       ./.local/share/Trash/info                           
4       ./.local/share/Trash/files                          
12      ./.local/share/Trash                                
44      ./.local/share
```

**new output:**

```
308     ./.g                                                                                       
4       ./.pof                                                                           
96      ./.local/share
```

the original command: `du -k`, and I'm trying with `awk` and `cut` commands but fails.

*edit:*- I got up to here:

```
du -k | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d "/" -f 1
```

Now, I'm struggling to merge similar lines and sum-up the first column.

**p.s this is just an output example***

thank you.

Comment: Show what you tried and we'll help you fix it, we won't write it from scratch for you.

Comment: `du -hc --maxdepth 1`

Comment: du --hc --max-depth 1 doesn't work because it doesn't sum-up the directories correctly. also, I tried something like that: du -k | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d "/" -f 1 but I have no experience in linux so it's wrong..

Comment: `du -sk .g .pof .local/share`

Comment: @rslemos : Maybe you should turn your comment into an answer....

Answer (score 0):

Use `du -d 1` to list accumulative content of 1 directory bellow current.

```
du -h -d 1
```

Provide a human readable count.

Comment: thank you but It doesn't sum-up the subdirectories with the directory, I checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with command:

```
du -sh *
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  du -sk .g .pof .local/share
```

The `-s` switch is summary, that is, `du` will search all the files, all the way down the folders inside, and report just the grand total. (The `-k` switch print the size in kilobytes; thanks Romeo Ninov).

You have to manually specify each folder you want to know the grand total of.

If you type, for example

```
  du -sk .
```

it will output just a single number, accounting for the current folder (and below) file sizes.

If you type

```
  du -sk *
```

the result will depend on what your shell expands `*` to (usually all the files and folders not starting with a dot (`.`) in the current folder).

Comment: `-k` print the size in kilobytes. This in heritage from UNIX time when w/o `-k` command print in 512 bytes blocks